# How do I create a batch file that copys and deletes files off a pi into a pc?

Tags: windows, batch, putty, raspberry-pi, sftp

I have a script on a Pi3 that creates files in:

```
home/pi/data/*csv
```

I am trying to write a bash script that uses PuTTY to copy and erase those files into a folder on my computer.

This is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

set "data='C:\Users\Recorded Data\%fullstamp%'"

echo Making Directory at: %data%
md %data%

cd C:\Programfiles
pscp @pi:/home/pi/data/*.csv %data%
pause
```

I saw that I have to use PSFTP to delete the files, but I also need to add a script to log into the pi?
I'm just kinda lost right now.

Answer (score 4):

Do something like this instead of `pscp`:

```
(
    echo get /home/pi/data/*.csv %data%
    echo rm /home/pi/data/*.csv
    echo exit
) | psftp @pi
```

Though this is not transitionally safe. If any file is created after `get` starts, but before `rm`, it will be deleted without being downloaded.

---

If you use WinSCP instead, you can use its [`get -delete`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_get) command for transactionaly-safe solution:

```
winscp.com /ini=nul /command ^
    "open sftp://username:password@pi/ -hostkey=""...""" ^
    "get -delete /home/pi/data/*.csv %data%" ^
    "exit"
```

WinSCP GUI can [generate a batch file template](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation#generating) like this one for you.

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

---

See also the same question on Stack Overflow:
[psftp.exe get files from the server and delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24577982/850848).